# How to ensure TravisCI builds don't run concurrently?

Tags: travis-ci

I have a build matrix for my tests. There are two builds that I don't want to run concurrently because they are hitting a remote server and if they both hit the server at the same time it would cause problems. Is there any settings to disable concurrency in the build matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There certainly is, you can dial down the maximum number of jobs that are run per repository: http://blog.travis-ci.com/2014-07-18-per-repository-concurrency-setting/